# Finding gray level which most of pixels have

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

[image]

Hi,
I have a histogram is shown above. I used `imhist(I)` function to get this histogram. I want to find the gray level which most of pixels have. 
Is it possible to find this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the two outputs of [`imhist`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/imhist.html) to obtain gray levels and count of each level. Use then the second output of [`max`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/max.html) to obtain the index of the level whose count is maximum. Finally, the result is the level with that index.

```
[count levels] = imhist(I); %// get levels and count of each level
[~, v] = max(count); %// v is the index corresponding to maximum count
result = levels(v); %// the result is the level that has that index
```